# How to download a file and get the path location locally

Tags: java

I have a URL i.e http://downloadplugins.verify.com/Windows/SubAngle.exe .
If I paste it on the tab and press enter then the file (SubAngle.exe) is getting downloaded and saved in the download folder. This is a manual process. But it can be done with java code.
I wrote the code for getting the absolute path with the help of the file name i.e SubAngle.exe.

Requirement:- With the help of the URL file gets downloaded,Verify the file has been downloaded and returns the absolute path of the file.

```
where  locfile is "http://downloadplugins.verify.com/Windows/SubAngle.exe"  

  public String downloadAndVerifyFile(String locfile) {
     File fileLocation = new File(locfile); 
     File fileLocation1 = new File(fileLocation.getName());
     String fileLocationPath = null;
     if(fileLocation.exists()){
      fileLocationPath = fileLocation1.getAbsolutePath();
  
     }
     else{
         throw new FileNotFoundException("File with name "+locFile+" may not exits at the location");
     }
     return fileLocationPath;
}
```

Comment: No, you should have a local path, which reflects a location on your disk, something like C:\Users\{your user name}\Downloads

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43157/easy-way-to-write-contents-of-a-java-inputstream-to-an-outputstream/51753#51753

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download and save a file from Internet using Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

easy and general function that im using:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public static void downLoadFile(String fromFile, String toFile) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        try {
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(fromFile), new File(toFile), 60000, 60000);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("exception on: downLoadFile() function: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing this huge code, go for **Apache's commons.io**
Try this:

```
URL ipURL = new URL("inputURL");
File opFile = new File("outputFile");
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(ipURL, opFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code to DownloadFile from URL**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class DownloadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            // URL("http://downloadplugins.verify.com/Windows/SubAngle.exe");
            System.out.println("Starting download");
            long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            URL url = new URL(args[0]);
            // Open the input and out files for the streams
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            in = conn.getInputStream();
            out = new FileOutputStream("YourFile.exe");
            // Read data into buffer and then write to the output file
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Time for download & save file in millis:"+(t2-t1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Display or throw the error
            System.out.println("Erorr while execting the program: "
                    + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            // Close the resources correctly
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Configure the value of fileName properly to know where the file is getting stored.**
 Source: http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/corejava/files/java-read-large-file-efficiently.html

**The source was modified to replace local file with http URL**

Output:

> java DownloadFile http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.7.1.RELEASE/e4.5/springsource-tool-suite-3.7.1.RELEASE-e4.5.1-updatesite.zip

**Starting download**

**Time for download & save file in millis:100184**

Comment: if you copy paste, at least use url and file provided by OP, also note your link is broken

Comment: That may be typo error. I have provided working link in "download'

Comment: What if the size of file is greater than 1 GB ?

Comment: It will handle since we are writing byte array of size 1024 bytes. It don't need 1 GB RAM but you just need 1 GB disk space. Let me know if you face issues with 1 GB file size. Add out.flush () after out.write()

Comment: On a different note of reading large file, have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508836/java-outofmemoryerror-in-reading-a-large-text-file/31724120#31724120

Comment: @ravindra: really? `byte[] response` sounds much like everything is in that byte[] before it gets written to disk

Comment: Small change is required in my code. After out.write (),write to fos immediately. Have a look at : http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/corejava/files/java-read-large-file-efficiently.html

Comment: Seriously, why would you read the file into a ByteArrayOutputStream?  Obviously this fails if the file is too big.  Not to mention that it is pointless and inefficient.

Comment: Have you checked the license of the code that you are copying?

Comment: @ravindra : Are you sure that this will work for >1GB file size?Because stiil byte array [1024] is being defined in the code. Thanks

Comment: I have changed the code to take filename as input from args[0]. 117 MB file is downloaded in 2 mins. e.g. java DownloadFile http://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/3.7.1.RELEASE/e4.5/springsource-tool-suite-3.7.1.RELEASE-e4.5.1-updatesite.zip