# How to download a big size file and get the path location locally

Tags: java

I referred to this link and the code works fine .
But what if the size of the file is more than 1 GB ? Can we write directly to output file on the disk instead of create an intermediate ByteArrayOutputStream ?

[How to download a file and get the path location locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231511/how-to-download-a-file-and-get-the-path-location-locally)

Comment: It works for 999 MB but does not work for 1 GB, is that correct?

Comment: Have you tried with a file more than 1 GB in size ? It should not matter. And: didn't ravindra already answer your question ?

Comment: We can't. But we can save each portion of data to disk, so we store only some (small) portion of data in memory.

Comment: Pleases don't create followup questions like this.  If you are unsatisfied with the answers to the original question, comment on them.  Or post a bonus.

Comment: @StephenC : I already commented for this ..Can you please answer my question ?
Is this code works for more than 1 GB file size?

Comment: No it doesn't work for large files, as I commented on the Answer.  (Or at least, it didn't last time I looked.)  However, I don't feel inclined to do your programming for you.  StackOverflow is a place to help >>programmers<< ... not people who just want to copy-and-paste other peoples' code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Instead of creating an intermediate `ByteArrayOutputStream` you can write the content of the file directly to disk (and you should!).

You can use the `InputStream` returned by URL and a `FileOutputStream`, or if you can use Java 8, you should use `Files.copy()`.

On the other hand, if you **can't** use Java 8, you can also use `IOUtils` from apache commons-io. It has a very simple method:

```
public static long copyLarge(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
```

here's a Java 8 example:

```
public void testDonwloadUsingJava8() throws Exception {

    URL image = new URL("http://learning.es/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/java.jpg");

    Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile("test-java8-", ".jpg");
    Files.copy(image.openStream(), tempFile, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

    System.out.println(tempFile.toString());
    System.out.println(tempFile.toFile().length());
}
```

Here's an example if you have to use an old version of java:

```
public void testDownloadFile() throws Exception{

    URL image = new URL("http://learning.es/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/java.jpg");

    File tempFile = File.createTempFile("test-", ".jpg");
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);

    try{

        IOUtils.copyLarge(image.openStream(), output);
    } finally {
        output.close();
    }

    System.out.println(tempFile.getPath());
    System.out.println(tempFile.length());
}
```

Comment: Can you please throw some light on the above code . What should i modify there or some reference to work on it ?

Comment: I've added some examples